# How to decode a base64 email with php?

Tags: php, base64, decode, gmail-api

I'm trying to decode my message with base 64 decode method. Does anybody know how to do this, or maybe via a php function?

```
<?php

class Gmail
{
    public function __construct($client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }
    public function readLabels()
    {
        $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($this->client);

        // Print the labels in the user's account.
        $user = 'me';
        $results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);


        $the_html = "";
        if (count($results->getLabels()) == 0) {
            // print "No labels found.\n";
            $the_html .= "<p>No labels found</p>";
        } else {
            // print "Labels:\n";
            $the_html .= "<p>labels</p>";


            foreach ($results->getLabels() as $label) {
                // printf("- %s\n", $label->getName());
                $the_html .= "<p>" . $label->getName() . "</p>";
            }
            return $the_html;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get list of Messages in user's mailbox.
     *
     * @param  Google_Service_Gmail $service Authorized Gmail API instance.
     * @param  string $userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
     * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
     * @return array Array of Messages.
     */
    public function listMessages()
    {
        $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($this->client);

        // Print the labels in the user's account.
        $userId = 'me';
        $pageToken = null;
        $messages = array();
        $opt_param = array();
        $messagesResponse = array();

        $i = 0;
        do {
            if ($i == 5) break;
            $i++;
            try {
                if ($pageToken) {
                    $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
                }
                $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
                if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) {
                    $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
                    $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        } while ($pageToken);

        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . '<br/>';
            $msg = $service->users_messages->get($userId, $message->getId());
            echo "<pre>" . var_export($msg->payload->parts[1]->body->data->base64_decode, true) . "</pre>";
        }

        return $messages;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean something like [`base64_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)?

Comment: If you post dozens lines of code (which usually us good and helpful) then you should also tell what the code is supposed to do and where it fails. Click on the [edit] link below your question to add more details, such as errormessages, example input, output etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the comment above by @Marvin, try to use `base64_decode` function.

Here is an example:

```php
$str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
echo base64_decode($str); // This is an encoded string
```

So in your case, instead of using

```php
echo "<pre>" . var_export($msg->payload->parts[1]->body->data->base64_decode, true) . "</pre>";
```

### try

```php
echo "<pre>" . var_export(base64_decode($msg->payload->parts[1]->body->data), true) . "</pre>";
```

---

### Reference

[base64_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)